# Does an extra SSID on a UniFi AP interfere with exiting ones?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, ssid, interference

I have a UniFi access point on which I have historically created a few SSIDs. I now would like to add a new one and I was wondering to which point such numerous SSIDs can be a problem (from an interference perspective)?

I do not see any setting for the channel in the setup of the SSID so I guess the answer is no but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Each SSID is associated with a Wireless Profile, so to the best of my knowledge the only restriction would be the number of wireless profiles,

There may be a limit on the number of Wireless Profiles you can have but that would be higher than most of us would ever need.

I have a Ubiquiti AP here.

Answer (score 0):

From the article
[UniFi's Advanced Wi-Fi Settings Explained](https://evanmccann.net/blog/2021/11/unifi-advanced-wi-fi-settings) :

> UniFi APs have a limit of either 4 or 8 SSIDs per band, per AP group. Some older models like the AC-Lite only support up to 4 per band. Most models can have up to 8. This means you can have up to eight 2.4 GHz and up to eight 5 GHz networks, or eight dual-band SSIDs. The same applies to 6 GHz.

If your model is not too old, the maximum is then 8 SSIDs per band.